# Rails 4 - Statesman Gem -method to define current state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, states

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4 and using Statesman for states.

In my project model, I want to display the :current_state of an object. However, I don't want the name of the attribute to appear. Instead, I want to write a human friendly state that can be rendered if the object is in the corresponding state.

For example, I have defined a state called :request_approval.

In my projects show page, I can write:

```
<%= @project.current_state %>
```

and the output is request_approval.

How can I write something that says if project is in current_state :request_approval, render: Awaiting a response to your request for approval?  Can I make some kind of method in my model to do that?

Comment: Create a `helper` method instead as you need that in view only. And you can use `switch case` inside may be

Comment: Hi Deep, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `projects_helper` you can write a method:

```
def text_for_state(state)
  case state
  when 'request_approval'
    'Awaiting Response'
  when 'something_else'
    'Then Something Else'
  end
end
```

And in your view just write:

```
<%= text_for_state(@project.current_state) %>
```

This is a option there may be better solutions to do this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I just renders blank where it should show the text

Comment: It works fine when I write (current_state) instead of state. Thanks very much